# Trying to call a script while passing two arguments

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a script that greps with `$1` and `$2`, first argument being a pattern and second being a file.

I need to create another script that calls this first one, passes the two arguments to it, and if the second is a directory, loops it on all the files in the directory.

Does anyone know how I'd go about this?  I keep coming close but failing miserably.

**EDIT**

Thought that the other post I had made didn't go through, Somehow got it lost.  I apologize to everyone,  so sorry.

Please forgive me. :(

Comment: Maybe if you showed your `grep` command or script people can point out where you got it wrong.

Answer (score 2):

```
if [[ -d $2 ]]; then
    find "$2" -type f -exec ./script "$1" {} \;
else
    ./script "$1" "$2"
fi
```

If `$2` is a directory then the `find` command finds all of the files in it and calls `./script` once for each file. The curly braces `{}` are a placeholder for these file names.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
[[ -d "$2" ]] && grep -e "$1" -r "$2" || grep -e "$1" "$2"
```

It tests whether arg 2 is a directory (bash syntax) and if so it invokes grep in recursive mode, otherwise in non-recursive.